# AngularJS Service in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an AngularJS service written in JavaScript and i would like to convert this to TypeScript. The Javascript version returns a function immediately. Why would it do this and how would I implement this in TypeScript?

**JavaScript**

```
Geisha.service("loginModal", ["$uibModal", "$rootScope", function ($uibModal: angular.ui.bootstrap.IModalService, $rootScope: ICustomRootScopeService) {
function assignCurrentUser(user: User) {
    $rootScope.currentUser = user;
    return user;
}

return function () {
    var instance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: "/Angular/Security/Views/loginTemplate.html",
        controller: "loginModalCtrl"
    });

    return instance.result.then(assignCurrentUser);
}}]);
```

**TypeScript**

In TypeScript I have only gone as far as creating the constructor and one of the methods but not sure how to implement the immediate return function

```
module G.Services {
export class LoginModal {

    $rootScope: ICustomRootScopeService;
    $uibModal: angular.ui.bootstrap.IModalService;

    static $inject = ["$rootScope", "$uibModal"];
    constructor($rootScope: ICustomRootScopeService, $uibModal: angular.ui.bootstrap.IModalService) {
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.$uibModal = $uibModal;
    }

    assignCurrentUser(user: User): User {
        this.$rootScope.currentUser = user;
        return user;
    }


}
Geisha.service("loginModal", LoginModal);}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to implement the immediate return function

In your case you have a `service that is just a function`. If you use a class it will be something *that has functions*. Better if you just use function as you had.

## Note

If you are willing to do the refactoring have `loginModal.assignCurrentUser(...stuff...)` elsewhere instead of `loginModal(...stuff...)`